# How do I push latest code into auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

How do I push latest code into auto scaling group's machines

I trying to run  production servers on `AWS` with `auto scaling framework`.

I wonder how can I deploy the new published code into running production servers.

I don't care the `down time` currently.

I run the web server with `nginx` with reverse proxy to  `puma`

What's the common practice to do this task ?

I think to login AWS console find all the servers IP and SSH into it. Update the codebase and restart the puma web server is not a good way to maintain quality product

Comment: You could look into ElasticBeanstalk https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how can I deploy the new published code into running
>   production servers.

Easy: you don't.

Instead, either update the AMI that the ASG instances are started from or update the launch configuration to include new code that gets deployed on boot.

Answer (score 1):

CodeDeploy has a really good integration with ASG groups at the moment, if you do choose to use it, just ensure that you are either baking the CodeDeploy agent into the AMI of your ASG or using user data to install the agent.  If you are baking into your AMI, just be aware that you will need to update the AMI every so often so it doesn't get over loaded with updates.

There are also extra scripts that AWS provides for ASG integration that will prevent autoscaling activities from replacing the instance while it's offline during an update and if you are using an ELB, it will also de-register it to prevent the ELB from sending traffic towards it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/auto-scaling-integ.html

As other posters have mentioned, Elastic Beanstalk is also an option.